# CONSTRAINT by checking value in other table

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I have items, categories and a items_category table like this:

```
table items
+----+-------+
| id | title |
+----+-------+

table categories
+----+------+------+
| id | name | main |
+----+------+------+

table items_categories
+---------+-------------+
| item_id | category_id |
+---------+-------------+
```

I need to make a constraint so that an item can have ONLY ONE main category, but otherwise, any amount of main = false categories. 
My initial thought was to set `UNIQUE(item_id, category_id)` but that is just limiting an item to one category.

Then I thought about having another column on the items_categories table called main which is an exact duplicate of the main column referenced by the category_id column, like this:

```
table items_categories
+---------+-------------+------+
| item_id | category_id | main |
+---------+-------------+------+

UNIQUE(item_id, category_id, main)
```

But that is not 100% normalized data and I would want to avoid that if possible.

Comment: If item can have only one category, then unique(item_id) is what you need

Comment: Sorry, just updated answer. An item can have any amount of categories, but only ONE main category.

Comment: How about adding a field `main_category_id` directly to the `items` table and creating a foreign key relationship to table categories? You would still retain table `items_categories` to model the secondary categories.

Comment: Oh it never occurred to me. It doesn't even make sense to store it in a many-to-many table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a [partial index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-partial.html):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX main_category_unique ON items_categories (item_id)
    WHERE main = TRUE;
```

Comment: Isn't this just creating an index for column **item_id** on table **items_categories** where main is true? I don't think that would be a solution. Would you want to further explain your answer?

Comment: @Doodlemeat I omited the `UNIQUE` keyword by mistake. Thanks.